# running a shell command in python get stuck

Tags: python, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to do automatic deployment to AWS beanstalk
with a Python script.

When performing the eb init there is a prompt which I can
deliver a parameter using the 'yes' command.
Even without the yes command, my eb init command get stuck.
I use:

```
os.chdir(folder)

os.system("yes n | eb init --region us-east-1 site")
```

I understand that I can use also subprocess but not sure 
exactly on how to use it.

Would love some help
Thanks.

Comment: about subprocess - https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

Comment: what do you mean by " get stuck" ?

Comment: @Amits: I don't think the problem is on the Python side. For debugging, I would first put the command into a file and execute it from the command line with `sh -x /absolute/path/to/script/file.sh`. For the safe side, I would also put a `pwd; env` line at the top of this file, so that we can check whether the working directory and the environment is correct. And, for this test (I'm a bit paranoid in this respect), I would also specify the absolute path for the `yes` and `eb` commands. After verifying that this shell script works correctly from the command line, I would invoke it from os.system.

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you

```
from subprocess import Popen
command='yes n | eb init --region us-east-1 site'
proc=Popen(command)
```